# How to run a .zip file

Tags: 16.04

Earlier this week, I decided to run my computer on Ubuntu, and I've been loving it! However, earlier tonight, I downloaded the game Hot Date to test out running games on my computer only to realize that I have no idea how to run it, or play it, or whatever the correct terminology is. I got the linux version, which came as a .zip file, and I'm running ubuntu 16.04, if that information helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unzip the ZIP file with your favourite archive manager, e. g. File Roller, which is associated with ZIP files by default in Ubuntu.
2. From the extracted files run `HotDateLinux/HotDateLinux2.x86`.

If you have a 64-bit installation of Ubuntu you will probably need to install the 32-bit variant of some shared libraries to run the game:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386
```

Answer (score 3):

Double clicking on the file should open it in Archive Manager. You can extract the file using the *Extract* button at the top of the window.

---

If you are looking to extract the zip file using the command line, the command is:

```
unzip myfile.zip
```

If it is not installed, run:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install unzip
```