# How to install TP-Link WN823N from zip file? Please give me proper instruction

Tags: tp-link

I need help to install by compile from zip file, in this zip file I saw an ".db" file & one folder mention that "Driver" & an instruction pdf. But I fetching Many errors. Pleas Help, what to do?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `lsmod | grep rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I need Installation method to compile from .zip file

Comment: We have no clue as to where you got the zip file. We don't know if it is new or old. We don't know if the source code was written for your kernel version and gcc version. We DO know that many of us here have worked with the WN823N previously and, most of the time, the downloadable file from TP-Link or included on the CD, will not properly compile. Please help us help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a .zip file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790849/how-to-run-a-zip-file)